# Keras custom layer how to have multiple returns

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm writing a custom layer in Keras with Tensorflow. The call function has multiple steps and I want to know if it's possible to skip some if a condition is met. 
For example, let's take this function:

```
def test_fn(x):
    if x < 10:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

Is there a way to do something like that in Keras?
I have something like this (simplified):

```
class Test_layer(layers.Layer):

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        test = get_test_fn(inputs)
        if test < 10:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1
```

I know the syntax there is wrong, but is there a way to do something equivalent?

Comment: Well, one solution is to use [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where): `return tf.where(test < 10, 0, 1)`.

Comment: @MikhailStepanov I think by tractable you mean differentiable, that is the issue generally.